# how to install netctl on lastest raspbian pi2

Tags: software-installation, pi-2, networking

I have install lasted raspbian on my raspberry pi2. Unfortunally, it seem that netctl isn't installed, so I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netctl
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package netctl
```

So, how to do to install netctl ? (I want it because of use qtnetctl : https://github.com/luebking/qnetctl)